# SharePoint paging control always show 1-30 even there are 400 items

Tags: document-library, view, paging

On our SP2013 on-premise farm there is a document library contains around 400 items. All these 400 items have individual permission (inheritance are broken).

If I open the libaray with All Site Content > Doc Library, the paging control is working as expected.

On one of page we have insert the Doc Libary as App. On that view the paging control always showing "1-30 >". When user click on ">" the page have changed but the control still show  "1-30 >". At the last page, the control disappear!Hence, user cannot switch to left page and cannot know the total number of items in libaray.

Is it known bug and can I work around it?

Comment: I have a similar issue, it occurred after I imported a site.